# Libreoffice in KDE Neon using GTK theming

Tags: kde, themes, libreoffice, gtk

So this is a weird one for me. I had to reinstall my KDE Neon desktop and after I did Libreoffice (which was before using my KDE theme) is now using my GTK theme and I have no idea as to why. Neither theme is the default as I've customised every detail of my computer's appearance but this was never an issue before. The two pictures are respectively my GTK and KDE themes. Please help me figure this one out.

[image: My GTK theme:]

[image: My KDE theme:]

Comment: Have you installed the libreoffice-kde package(it is a package that I always uninstall because it introduces performance issues) but is supposed to cater for kde integration? Also note that KDE neon is not an official Ubuntu flavor and therefore not supported on askubuntu.

Comment: Even the KDE Neon devs don't recommend installing KDE Neon on Kubuntu.

Comment: So installing libreoffice-kde did nothing although thanks to Bruni for the suggestion. Also thanks for the unsupported tip as well. Also to clarify this  wasn't installed on top of Kubuntu it was a fresh install from an ISO.

Comment: So after I restarted my computer Bruni's solution then took effect. So thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the `libreoffice-kde` package (it is a package that I always uninstall because it introduces performance issues). It is supposed to cater for KDE integration.

You may have to log out and back in or even reboot for the changes to take effect.